# c++ - Why is call to nested inherited abstract constructor required?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, abstract

Topic may be confusing, so here's the code example (sandbox [here](http://cpp.sh/9cmga)):

```
class AbstractA {
 protected:
  int wibble_;
 public:
  AbstractA(int wibble) : wibble_(wibble) { }
  virtual ~AbstractA() { }
  virtual void DoThing(void) = 0;  // Pure virtual method.
};

class AbstractB : public virtual AbstractA {
 public:
  AbstractB(int wibble) : AbstractA(wibble) { }
  virtual ~AbstractB() { }
  virtual void DoOtherThing(void) = 0;  // Pure virtual method.
};

class DerivedA : public AbstractA {
 public:
  DerivedA(int wibble) : AbstractA(wibble) { }
  virtual ~DerivedA() { }
  virtual void DoThing(void) { wibble_ = 1; }  // Implement pure virtual method.
};

class DerivedB : public AbstractB {
 public:
  //DerivedB(int wibble) : AbstractB(wibble) { }  // Error -- see below.
  DerivedB(int wibble) : AbstractA(wibble), AbstractB(wibble) { }  // Works.
  virtual ~DerivedB() { }
  virtual void DoThing(void) { wibble_ = 2; }  // Implement AbstractA method.
  virtual void DoOtherThing(void) { wibble_ = 3; }  // Implement AbstractB method.
};
```

I have two abstract classes, `AbstractA`  and `AbstractB`.  `AbstractB` inherits from `AbstractA` using the `virtual` keyword, so `DoThing()` remains pure virtual.  The `AbstractB` constructor calls the constructor for `AbstractA`, which initializes the `wibble_` data member.

I then have two derived classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`.  `DerivedA` inherits `AbstractA`, calls `AbstractA(int)` from its constructor, and implements `AbstractA::DoThing()`.  Similarly, `DerivedB` inherits and implements `AbstractB`.

Here's the part I don't get.  `DerivedB` doesn't inherit `AbstractA` directly.  But the compiler insists that a call to a constructor of `AbstractA` is implicit in the constructor of `DerivedB`.  If I try to use the first `DerivedB` constructor, commented out in the example, I get this error:

```
foo.h: In constructor 'DerivedB::DerivedB(int)':
foo.h:31:42: error: no matching function for call to 'AbstractA::AbstractA()'
```

So why is it necessary for `DerivedB` to call the constructor of a class (`AbstractA`) that its base class (`AbstractB`) inherited?  I mean, `AbstractB(int)` calls `AbstractA(int)` in its initializer, so doesn't calling `AbstractA(wibble), AbstractB(wibble)` effectively call `AbstractA(wibble)` twice -- once directly, once from `AbstractB()`'s constructor?

Comment: *"`AbstractB` inherits from `AbstractA` using the `virtual` keyword, so `DoThing()` remains pure virtual."* These two facts are unrelated. `DoThing` would remain pure virtual with or without virtual inheritance.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Ah, thank you, yes, that's a good point.  Also, thanks to folks for marking this as a duplicate.  It was a matter of knowing exactly what sort of question I was trying to ask.